# HDFS Encryption using Java

Tags: java, hadoop, encryption, hdfs

I want to invoke below command using java .

```
hadoop key create myKey
hdfs crypto -createZone -keyName myKey -path /zone
```

Can someone point to java api documentation for this or any example to implement this in java?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for "Runtime.exec" or the ProcessBuilder class to execute an external program.

Comment: No. I need java api information for commands that i mentioned in question.